# jQuery each() help

Tags: jquery

I have this structure

```
<p class="descr">
  <span>something here</span>
  <img src="test" />
</p>

<p class="descr">
  <span>somthing else here</span>
  <img src="test2" />
  <img src="test3" />
</p>
```

so there can be more than one image inside of a `<p>` element.

What i need to do is loop through each `<p>` and then each `<img>` inside of it and add something to the front of it. Any help is appreciated. I tried doing an `.each()` but it's not working.

Comment: Why don't you post the code you tried?

Comment: Please post the code you currently have. People can help you better if they can *see* what you've been doing wrong. Hint: You can edit it right into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('p.descr > img').each(function() {
    // Make this code do what you want.
    $(this).prepend('<span>Prepended Content</span>');
});
```

The variable `this` represents the current image inside this function. In this example, I'm injecting a `span` element before each image inside a paragraph, but only direct descendant images.

This function can be shortened if you're only going to add another element before each image:

```
$('p.descr > img').prepend('<span>Prepended Content</span>');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('p').each(function()
{
    $(this).find('img').each(function()
    {
        // do stuff with the image
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be advisable to combine the `each` statements to prevent unnecessary DOM traversal.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p.desc img').before('<span>here comes an image</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p img').each(
  function(k, v)
  {
    $($(v).parents()[0] + 'span').html('Your text here');
  }
);
```

[Manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('p.descr img').before('<span>New Stuff</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p = $('#p img');
p.each( function(i, val) { 
    $(val.id).append("<strong>Hello</strong>");
});
```